# What is the difference between "{$var1}someString" and "$var1someString"?

Tags: php, variables

I can make out the difference between

```
echo "{$var1}someString" // here the variable is $var1
echo "$var1someString"   // here the variable is $var1someString
```

The question is why to use `{}`?  It works only with `{}`.  It does not work with `()`. What is so special about `{ }`?

Comment: I guess, that's because the syntax says so?

Comment: why it doesn't works for () is something that is breaking my head, I guess it is { } block separator, and it separates block, but why not () they are also separate expression, why ????

Comment: The syntax is defined to work this way. You don't ask why you create a function ($var) {code}. It's just defined this way.

Comment: So basically, the question is why are there curly braces and not some other braces?

Answer (score 4):

The curly braces `{}` are used in that way to identify variables within strings:

```
echo "{$var1}someString"
```

If you look at:

```
echo "$var1someString"
```

PHP can't possibly determine that you wanted to echo `$var1`, it's going to take all of it as the variable name.

You could concatenate your variables instead:

```
echo $var1 . "someString"
```

It doesn't work for `()` simply because the PHP designers choose `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

you expained it yourself. thats simply the syntax php uses for this - nothing more. to quote [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>   Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then **wrap it in { and }**. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), the curly part is called complex syntax. It basically allows you to use complex expressions inside string.

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
// Show all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$great = 'fantastic';

// Won't work, outputs: This is { fantastic}
echo "This is { $great}";

// Works, outputs: This is fantastic
echo "This is {$great}";
echo "This is ${great}";

// Works
echo "This square is {$square->width}00 centimeters broad."; 


// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";


// Works
echo "This works: {$arr[4][3]}";

// This is wrong for the same reason as $foo[bar] is wrong  outside a string.
// In other words, it will still work, but only because PHP first looks for a
// constant named foo; an error of level E_NOTICE (undefined constant) will be
// thrown.
echo "This is wrong: {$arr[foo][3]}"; 

// Works. When using multi-dimensional arrays, always use braces around arrays
// when inside of strings
echo "This works: {$arr['foo'][3]}";

// Works.
echo "This works: " . $arr['foo'][3];

echo "This works too: {$obj->values[3]->name}";

echo "This is the value of the var named $name: {${$name}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of getName(): {${getName()}}";

echo "This is the value of the var named by the return value of \$object->getName(): {${$object->getName()}}";

// Won't work, outputs: This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}
echo "This is the return value of getName(): {getName()}";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `{}` define that variable within these are not a simple string so php pic up that variable value instead of assuming that as a simple string.